# How can i get the apk installed on avd emulator?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, apk, emulation

Basically I want to pull the apidemo.apk file from avd emulator and  install it to my android device.
I don't need source code .

Answer (score 0):

You can find the APK file in your Android Studio project folder ../app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk

Copy that APK into your Android device and install it.

If the folder does not exist, go to Build > Build APK.